# how do I pull a remote tracking branch while in the master branch

Tags: git

I'm in master and I do a git pull, I get a message indicating I need to pull a remote branch.

Typically I do a *git co [branch]* then *git pull/rebase*.

Is there a way to git pull/rebase of [branch] without having to do a *git co [branch]* first?

Answer (score 2):

If you combine Apikot and Jeremy you get:

```
git pull --rebase origin branch
```

Or, if you haven't set the branch mapping up in your config:

```
git pull --rebase origin <src>:<dst>
```

Answer (score 0):

git pull origin branch

Sorry, forgot to mention that pull merges.

If you can use git fetch origin branch to just fetch that branch. http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html

Comment: This appears to try to merge the branch with master.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do an operation on a branch without switching to it. But you can combine the pull and rebase by doing git pull --rebase origin

Comment: Aye.  I'm lazy, so I just set the rebase=true option for the branch in my .git/config.